# How to place widget to the bottom inside Form widget?

Tags: flutter

I have widget:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: ...,
  body: Form(
    child: ListView(
      children: [
        ...
        ElevatedButton() // Save button
      ]
    )
  )
);
```

[image: img]

So, I want to place it to the bottom of the screen. I tried to place it inside `Align` widget but it doesn't work. Another thing is that I have `ExpansionTile` above and it can overflow the screen. In this case, there mustn't be any additional space between `Activate` and `Save` buttons. How to do it?

Comment: why your Form have children ? 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html

Comment: You're right. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween. Documentation:

> Place the free space evenly between the children.

```
bool _hasExpansionTile = false;

Scaffold(
  appBar: ...,
  body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: _hasExpansionTile ? MainAxisAlignment.start : MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, /// Checking that the expansion tile is visible
        children: [
          Flexible(
             child: Form(
                child: Column(
                    children: [
                       ...
                    ],
                ),
             ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("Send")),
        ],
      ),
);
```

Of course you must use setState(), when you changing the value of the `_hasExpansionTile` property.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but what to do with this requirement
`Another thing is that I have ExpansionTile above and it can overflow the screen. In this case, there mustn't be any additional space between Activate and Save buttons.`

Comment: Check that expansion tile is visible.
`mainAxisAlignment: _hasExpansionTile ? MainAxisAlignment.start : MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,`

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that simple in my case, because `ExpansionTile`'s items can be modified (add/delete/edit) so it may not overflow the screen even if expanded. Also, `MainAxisAlignment.start` doesn't help, it still overflows with error

Comment: So, your answer is almost right. One thing - you need to wrap `Form` widget in `Flexible`

Comment: Not tested, but updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spacer()

```
Scaffold( appBar: ...,
body: Form(
child: ListView(
  children: [
    ...
    Spacer(),
    ElevatedButton() // Save button
  ]
)
```

)
);